# Date format in VB

Tags: vb.net, date

i am using the following expression to get the date :

```
 SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("COLLECTIONDATE").DefaultValue =   Date.Today.ToShortDateString
```

The output in the `GridPanel` in `EXt` shows only the date , that's what i want , but when i want to see the output in a textfield it shows me : `"2013-05-20T00:00:00.000"` , i don't know why the time is showing , any idea how to remove the time from showing in the textfield ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 Date.Today.ToString("MM/dd/YYYY")
```

"MM/dd/YYYY" This is date format. You can also apply your date format.

Fo more detail on get formatted date visit this link. **[Click Here...](http://jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com/2013/02/beginning-net-get-formatted-date-time.html)**

Comment: i don't think we can do that : i got this : `The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 6.`

Comment: What is the datatype of "COLLECTIONDATE" column ?

Comment: That's because it should be **lower-case** `y`s.  Change `YYYY` to `yyyy`.  *The `M` is correct as lower-case `m` is for minutes, while `M` is for month.

Comment: @JayeshSorathia `COLLECTIONDATE` is `DateTime` in the `Updateparameters` there is no `type="Date"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what GridPanel is, but you are setting **value** format. Instead you want to be setting **column** format of whatever UI element you have at your disposal for displaying data. My assumption here is that you are using a table there.

Answer (score 0):

It might be **datetime datatype**

Try this to formatting on your datagriview ..

I assumed dgv as datagridview control ....

```
Private Sub dgv_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellFormatting
    Dim sHeader As String = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name

    If sHeader = "date" Then '--- change with your column name
        If e IsNot Nothing Then
            If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                Try
                    e.Value = DateTime.Parse(e.Value.ToString()).ToLongDateString()                        
                    e.FormattingApplied = True
                Catch ex As FormatException
                    e.Value = ""
                End Try
            End If
        End If
    End If
End sub
```